# How to Spawn additional Rectangles in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pygame

I'm creating a simple game and I got stuck on a problem.

The game goes like this: 
"White square" eats "Green Squares"

**Question:**
How can I spawn "New Red squares" and remain on screen each time the "White square" eats a "Green square" ?

Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import*


pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Square-it")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

"Green Square"
green_x = randint(10, 780)
green_y = randint(10, 580)
green_width = 15
green_height = 15
green_color = pygame.Color("green")
green = pygame.Rect(green_x, green_y, green_width, green_height)

"Red Square"
red_x = randint(20, 780)
red_y = randint(20, 580)
red_width = 10
red_height = 10
red_color = pygame.Color("red")
red = pygame.Rect(red_x, red_y, red_width, red_height)

"White Square"
white_x = 400
white_y = 300
white_width = 10
white_height = 10
white_color = pygame.Color("white")
white = pygame.Rect(white_x, white_y, white_width, white_height)

while True:

    clock.tick(60)
    gameDisplay.fill((0, 20, 5))
    gameDisplay.fill(white_color, white)
    gameDisplay.fill(green_color, green)
    gameDisplay.fill(red_color, red)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           sys.exit()

    '''When White eats Green, Green regenerates'''
    if white.colliderect(green):
        green = pygame.Rect(randint(10, 780), randint(10, 580), green_width, green_height)

    '''White Square Movement'''
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        white.left = white.left - 10

    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        white.right = white.right + 10

    if keys[K_UP]:
        white.top = white.top - 10

    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        white.bottom = white.bottom + 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create an array to store all your red rectangle instances

```
red_square_list = []
```

When your white rectangle collide the green rectangle, you should extract x,y position of the green rectangle and create an instance of red rectangle at this position.

To do it, I would recommend to work with classes but first you can create a function to create a red rectangle:

```
def create_red_square(x, y)
    red_width = 10
    red_height = 10
    red_color = pygame.Color("red")
    red = pygame.Rect(red_x, red_y, red_width, red_height)
    return red
```

Now, everytime white collides green, you have to extract the green rectangle position and display a red one with the function above :

```
if white.colliderect(green):
    pos_x, pos_y = green.left, green.top
    green = pygame.Rect(randint(10, 780), randint(10, 580), green_width, green_height)
    red_square_list.append(create_red_square(pos_x, pos_y))
```

The last line is only to store the red rectangle if you want to use them later (like you do for green / white rectangle)

I hope it helps,

***EDIT #1:***

I made some small mistakes is the previous code, this is a working solution :

`
    import pygame, sys
    from random import randint
    from pygame.locals import*

```
red_square_list = []

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Square-it")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
red_color = pygame.Color("red")

"Green Square"
green_x = randint(10, 780)
green_y = randint(10, 580)
green_width = 15
green_height = 15
green_color = pygame.Color("green")
green = pygame.Rect(green_x, green_y, green_width, green_height)

def create_red_square(x, y):
    """Return one instance of Rect at position x, y"""
    red_width = 10
    red_height = 10
    red = pygame.Rect(x, y, red_width, red_height)
    return red

"White Square"
white_x = 400
white_y = 300
white_width = 10
white_height = 10
white_color = pygame.Color("white")
white = pygame.Rect(white_x, white_y, white_width, white_height)

while True:

    clock.tick(60)
    gameDisplay.fill((0, 20, 5))
    gameDisplay.fill(white_color, white)
    gameDisplay.fill(green_color, green)
    for each in red_square_list: #display all red rect
        gameDisplay.fill(red_color, each)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           sys.exit()

    '''When White eats Green, Green regenerates'''
    if white.colliderect(green):
        # extract green rect position
        pos_left, pos_top = green.left, green.top 
        # store the new red rectangle in the array
        red_square_list.append(create_red_square(pos_left+2, pos_top+2))
        # +2 is required as red square are 10x10 and green 15x15
        # new rect green
        new_left = randint(10, 780)
        new_top = randint(10, 580)
        green = pygame.Rect(new_left, new_top, green_width, green_height)


    '''White Square Movement'''
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
    white.left = white.left - 10

    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        white.right = white.right + 10

    if keys[K_UP]:
        white.top = white.top - 10

    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        white.bottom = white.bottom + 10
```

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you Nicolas M. for your effort, unfortunately i tried it and it still doesn't work for me :/

Comment: is there a way where, when white collide Green,, to spawn a new Red square randomly in the screen and remain at its position?

Comment: Sorry I made 2 mistakes (incorrect position of the square, to be shifted by 2px), I forgot to add a loop to dispay them all and declare the color out of the function. Now it works !